# Implement onItemClickedListener with ListActivity in Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

It's possible to implement onItemClickedListener() while I can't get list by id, because my ListView got android:id="@android:id/list"?

I want to check if ListItem is clicked and highlight it. Now I can't get item highlighted.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class FirstGridPage extends ListActivity {
      private StolikiDataSource datasource;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_list_stoliki);

    datasource = new StolikiDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Stoliki> values = datasource.getAllStoliki();

    // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Stoliki> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Stoliki>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  // Will be called via the onClick attribute
  // of the buttons in main.xml
  public void onClick(View view) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter<Stoliki> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Stoliki>) getListAdapter();
    Stoliki stolik = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
      String[] stoliki_numer = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
      String[] stoliki_opis = new String[] { "Czerwony", "Niebieski", "Zielony" };
      int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
      // Save the new comment to the database
      stolik = datasource.createStolik(stoliki_numer[nextInt], stoliki_opis[nextInt]);
      adapter.add(stolik);
      break;
    case R.id.delete:
      if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
          stolik = (Stoliki) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
        datasource.deleteStolik(stolik);
        adapter.remove(stolik);
      }
      break;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class TestActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I read firstly Egor answer, google the implementation and write same code as you. Both thanks. Everything working fine. Thank you. Now I must check which index of item is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

`ListActivity` has a [onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method, you just need to override it.